# Embed Large Text File into C++Builder Windows App

Tags: text, embed, c++builder

I want to embed a large dictionary text file (more than 66k words of no more than 30 characters per word, with one word per line) into a C++Builder executable to run on Windows. How can that be done?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Rather than embed the text file into the executable itself, you could just store the file in the same folder as the executable (or any other folder of your choosing), and then load the file at runtime using a `TStringList` object using its `LoadFromFile()` method.

Otherwise, if you really want to embed the file, you can store its content in a resource in the executable, by referring to the file with an [`.rc` script](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/menurc/about-resource-files) added to the project (or, using the [Project > Resources and Images...](https://docwiki.embarcadero.com/RADStudio/en/Resources_and_Images) dialog), and then load the resource data into a `TStringList` object at runtime using its `LoadFromStream()` method with a `TResourceStream`.  See [Resource Files Support](https://docwiki.embarcadero.com/RADStudio/en/Resource_Files_Support) in Embarcadero's documentation for further details and an example.

Answer (score 1):

Successfully used the [Resource Files Support](https://docwiki.embarcadero.com/RADStudio/Alexandria/en/Resource_Files_Support) link to embed a short text list file into a sample exe file.